# EPUB: HTML Form value to an existing .XML file

Tags: javascript, html, xml, epub

Can someone tell me. Is it possible to save a data value from html form going to an existing .xml file within an epub through javascript??

Creating a new .xml inside the epub file was not possible, so im wondering of another option. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to do? What do you mean by "save"? Are you trying to permanently modify the e-book? If I understand your question correctly, you might consider saving the information into local storage, and then use JS at the appropriate time to retrieve it and populate it into the DOM.

Comment: @torazaburo im not trying to modify it. I just want to save data values for example: a score. So if they answer the true or false page on the epub their score will be recorded on an existing xml inside the epub file. Is that posible? epub will be run on tablets or ipad only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not modify or rewrite the XML/XHTML files which make up the book. The way that you would handle this is to run JS on page load which retrieves any stored information from local storage, and inserts it into the appropriate place in the DOM.

Comment: This works, I appreciate it. Thanks men. But now i got new problem. My boss wants the EPUB file to be viewed on the browser just like a pdf without seeing its content or page source.

Comment: An e-book is an e-book and a PDF is a PDF. It's not trivial to convert an e-book to a PDF. If you just want to view the e-book in your browser, google for "view e-book in browser". You will find some plug-ins and add-ons. In addition, it is reported that upcoming versions of MS Edge will be able to read e-books. However, I don't believe that any of these solutions will cloak the source.

Comment: got lucky to found plugins for firefox. But its not an accurate reader. Theres a lot of contents not loading or executed on the browser. Anyways thanks a lot @torazaburo for giving me ideas and knowledge about this